# Extracting German restaurants from planet.osm?

Tags: openstreetmap, point-of-interest

I want to get the data out of http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm

I have just come back from the site http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm

which has got some files that belong to the openstreetmap-Project. i downloaded a similar file that is derived from a German Mirrorsite - this one here:

http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/download.geofabrik.de/

i downloaded the file called  germany.osm,bz2

according  to this instruction

> type bzip2 -d planet.osm.bz2; or your OS may support double-click
>   unpacking. See Wikipedia's list of compression programs.

i did the following - but without success-,

```
martin@linux-wyee:~/poi_abzug/geofabrik> bzip2 -d germany.osm,bz2;
bzip2: Can't open input file germany.osm,bz2: No such file or directory.
```

Can anybody explain why i did not succeed?

further **questions:**

- Is this a XML-File ?

I only need the data for the Pois in Germany: can i use this file here - http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/

As this might be of general interest i think that many users can benefit from an answer to this question.

So my **question** is:

- How to read the above mentioned dataset - how to read it - on a OpenSuse-Linux-machine!?
- Should i do it in  the terminal?

Note - i want to store all in a csv file - and i look for all the restaurants... What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You certainly don't need Planet.osm if you only want to look for POIs in Germany. Germany.osm listed e.g. in http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/download.geofabrik.de/ will be enough.

Comment: hello dear underdark - many many thanks for the answer. **Note;** i have written an update - **see above** I am happy that you pointed me to the right source. Unfortunatly i have some issues to open the file in Opensuse 12.1 - i want to inspect the data - and have a closer look . is it possible to have a look at the xml data - eg. the name of the entity  - which is the name of   a restaurant, then the street  and some times even some additional infos. Is it possible to extract those data out of the above mentioned file!? Look forward to hear from you - greetings

Comment: Your command did not succeed because the file is named germany.osm.bz2 instead of the germany.osm,bz2 you typed. Only a small difference for your eyes, but a big for the computer ;-)

Comment: btw. are you 100% sure that your filename is germany.osm,bz2 usually there is no , in filenames just . (dot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cloudmate to download OSM data in shape file format per country.
Check the following link:

http://downloads.cloudmade.com/

Comment: can i do some requests on POIs of Openstreetmap with XAPI.
doing like so: i send a request to the  API-Server - over http
as a respond i get the following result - in XML 
example: the following link gives back all the Nodes of the Type amenity=restaurant in XML-Format. the bounding box (bbox) limits the area:
http://xapi.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]

what do you say!?

Comment: Looks like cloudmate dismitted this service. Today http://downloads.cloudmade.com/ will redirect you to 404 (page not found)

Answer (score 4):

As Underdark noted, you don't need to use planet.osm, but instead use the link she provided contains all data (included restaurants) within Germany.

You'll want to use [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis), an OSM data parser. (Check out the [detailed usage page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage) to find out more of how to use osmosis, if you're interested.

There may be other ways in osmosis to do it, 
The following filter should leave you with a file that removes all ways and nodes that DO NOT have the value amenity=restaurant (since Restaurants could be coded in OSM as a node or a way). You have to run 3 commands, as follows:

osmosis --read-xml input.osm --tf accept-nodes amenity=restaurant --write-xml output-nodes.osm

osmosis --read-xml input.osm --tf accept-ways amenity=restaurant --write-xml --used-node output-ways.osm

osmosis --rx output-ways.osm --rx output-nodes.osm --merge --wx merged.osm

As for getting it into a CSV file ? Not sure, but I don't think there's a particular program that directly exports OSM to CSV. Is there a particular reason you want it into a CSV file ? If you're using an application that supports imports of CSV, it might also support other file formats that .OSM data could be exported into.

Comment: just looking for the mirror  of osmosis pepo for opensuse 12.1 http://ftp.suse.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_Factory/noarch/osmosis-0.39-1.7.noarch.rpm.mirrorlist is this the path that i need..?

Comment: can i do some requests on POIs of Openstreetmap with XAPI.
doing like so: i send a request to the  API-Server - over http
as a respond i get the following result - in XML 
example: the following link gives back all the Nodes of the Type amenity=restaurant in XML-Format. the bounding box (bbox) limits the area:
http://xapi.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]

what do you say!?

Answer (score 2):

Try Overpass, it gives easy access to search POI data from openstreetmap.

Or get the germany.osm data dump and use **[this link](https://github.com/MorbZ/OsmPoisPbf)** to get the POIs as a CSV file.

(Problems with unzipping a bzip2 file should probably be asked on another stackexchange site)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/MorbZ/OsmPoisPbf

Check above link and download osmpois.jar

This will parse the .osm.pbf file and will creates .csv file with containing tag type,tag name ,tag id,longitude, latitude